# My pdo results are duplicating in Tables

Tags: php, html, pdo, html-table

I have a leaderboard which tells me what people are ontop with their Money (Virtual currency for testing purposes).
So it works, it shows everything from my tables through **PDO (PHP Data Objects)**.

The problem is, I let it output in a table. But for every id theres being made a second table like this:

[image]

the code im using:

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test1','root','####'); 

$sql = "SELECT naam, id, days, money FROM user ORDER BY money DESC "; 
$results = $db->query($sql); 



foreach($results as $row) 
{ 

?>


<html>
<head>



</head>
<body>
<TABLE BORDER="5"    WIDTH="100%"   CELLPADDING="4" CELLSPACING="3">
   <TR>
      <TH><BR><H3>POINTS LEADERBOARD</H3>
      </TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TH>Username</TH>
      <TH>Money</TH>
      <TH>Days</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD><?php echo $row['naam']; ?></TD>
      <TD><?php echo $row['money']?></TD>
      <TD><?php echo $row['days']?></TD>
   </TR>
</TABLE>

<?php
/*
echo "<table>";
echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TH><BR><H3>POINTS LEADERBOARD</H3>";
    echo "</TH>";
echo "</TR>";

echo "<TR>";
echo "<TH>Username</TH>";
echo "<TH>Money</TH>";
echo "<TH>Days</TH>";
echo "</TR>";

echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TD>";    echo $row['naam']; echo "</TD>";
    echo "<TD>";    echo $row['money']; echo "</TD>";
    echo "<TD>";    echo $row['days']; echo "</TD>";
echo "</TR>";
echo "</table>";
*/
?>




<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me or tell me what im doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the code surrounding the html, eg the loop

Comment: that cannot be the whole script

Comment: No, i updated it now

Comment: Please do not post code on external sites. It is unclear how long your code will stay up there. This would render your question (and its possible solution) impossible to uderstand to a future audience.

Comment: Iknow, everytime i try to post my code, it formats it too compiled code...

Comment: Just check your formatting. You probably have a problem with whitespace. It's not too difficult to figure out. :)

Answer (score 2):

The way you have the opening `html` etc tags within the loop is wrong - perhaps something like this?

```
<?php 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test1','root','####'); 
    $sql = 'SELECT naam, id, days, money FROM user ORDER BY money DESC '; 
    $results = $db->query($sql); 
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>leaderboard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        echo "
            <TABLE BORDER='5' WIDTH='100%' CELLPADDING='4' CELLSPACING='3'>
               <TR>
                  <TH><BR><H3>POINTS LEADERBOARD</H3></TH>
               </TR>
               <TR>
                  <TH>Username</TH>
                  <TH>Money</TH>
                  <TH>Days</TH>
               </TR>";

        foreach($results as $row) { 
            echo "
               <TR>
                  <TD>{$row['naam']}</TD>
                  <TD>{$row['money']}</TD>
                  <TD>{$row['days']}</TD>
               </TR>";
        }
        echo "</TABLE>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code works half :D, it works in the way like: it doesnt duplicate it anymore, but it duplicates only the table heads like Username Money and Days

Comment: Aaah i fixed it, placed the TH's also above the Foreach,

Comment: Put only the rows inside the loop

Comment: @luc-stey if this solved your problem, then please mark it as such. Thank you.